# How to get name of current network in AdMob mediation?

Tags: android, admob

I use `onAdLoaded` event of AdMob SDK to stop some app related functions while AdMob ad is showing but I only want to do this when a specific ad network's ad is shown (video).

I need something like `Admob.getNetworkInfoFor(interstitialAd_instance)`...

How can I do this without manually implementing a custom adapter for related network? (Original adapter is coded by 3rd party ad network as closed source and I don't want to implement it again by myself again)

Is there a way to get currently selected ad network's name/id/info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at AdView's [getMediationAdapterClassName](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView.html#getMediationAdapterClassName()) method.  If the impression has gone to third-party mediation, that will return the name of the adapter class that's in use.  It may return null in some cases where AdMob fill is chosen, so check for that as well.

Comment: I was looking to find a solution for InterstitialAd not for AdView; but, I saw that the method you have shared is also valid for InterstitialAd and this solves the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Yep. I meant to show InterstitialAd. That'll teach me to answer too quickly. Glad it helped, though.